How do I describe these cabinet hinges?
I want to replace the hinges on my kitchen cabinet and what I've learned so far in researching this is that there are tons of different types of hinges.  When looking for hinges online I want to be sure I m ticking all of the boxes in describing the hinge.  Can somebody verify for me that I am describing these correctly.  I think what I need are:
Face frame 3/8" overlay wrap around hinges.
That is the overlay on the hinge side of the door is 3/8 of an inch and since I have framed cabinets I need partial/full wrap around hinges. They are not inset since the door sits on top of the frame.
Do I have the description correct?  I'm attaching a couple of pictures.  Somebody's help is really appreciated.



That is correct, wrap around hinges. Specify the dimensions they need to wrap around, the angle to which the door needs to open, and how much the door overlays the face of the cabinet
